# Automatically crafting Buildcraft Mining Wells

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-buildcraft

Minecraft Version: 1.2.5
Mods: Buildcraft plus additional pipes plus logistics pipes, equivalent exchange, thaumcraft, IndustrialCraft, Forestry, RedPower2

Using the Buildcraft automatic crafting table in conjunction with the crafting logistics pipes, I've set up a large autocrafting system (currently 68 items, and always expanding), but I am running into an issue with adding the mining well to my system. The mining well requires an iron pickaxe, and those do not stack. Furthermore, the crafting pipe will not craft an item from an an automatic crafting table if there is not more than 1 item in each stack.

Is it possible (and if so, how is it done) to have an automatic crafting table craft items that require non-stacking items without having to babysit the automatic crafting table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An automatic crafting table can use items from a chest immediately adjacent to it.

You can use the satellite chest feature of logistics pipes to send some items (such as iron pickaxes) to the satellite chest instead of the crafting table.

Comment: Do you have a video link to how satellites work?